# How to add Date and Time in form field

Tags: php, forms, calendar

I am building a application form and I want to add a field for visitors to select a date and time. How would I be able to add that to the drop down field that I have added so far. I thinking for a calendar and time dropdown would work for this type of form? I have added the `div` tag below.

```html
<div class="col-md-12 vehicle-assessment">
  <h6>Hirer Details </h6>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tia_lineholder_text" id="tia_lineholder_email">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery datepicker
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

or you can use

```
<input type="date" name="date" />
```

but the last solution wont work for all browsers, if you want to use cross browser than you should use datepicker plugin or any other plugins available on internet

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a dropdown menu this would be done like this assuming you have a list of `DateTime` objects. Time would be done in a similar way.

```html
<div class="col-md-12 vehicle-assessment">
  <h6>Hirer Details </h6>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tia_lineholder_text" id="tia_lineholder_email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Date</label>
    <select id="date">
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <?php
      // Assuming $dates is a list of DateTime Objects
      foreach $date in $dates {
        echo "<option value='" . $date->getTimestamp() . "'>" . $date->format('Y-m-d') . "</option>";
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I'd suggest using the inputs [time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) and [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date). If you have specific time frames you want people to insert this can be added by `min` and `max`. If you need additional constraints you could alway write some JS-Code to enforce no sunday or something like that.

```html
    <div class="col-md-12 vehicle-assessment">
      <h6>Hirer Details </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tia_lineholder_text" id="tia_lineholder_email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="date"
               value="2018-07-22"
               min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31" />
      </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date</label>
        <input type="time" name="time"
               min="0:00" max="24:00" required />
      </div>
    </div>
```